# Running a script bash with using VTE module

Tags: python, bash, vte

I'm trying to use the VTE module to run a script bash:
I have several errors,
One of them is:

```
avconv version 9.11-6:9.11-2ubuntu2, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 24 2014 06:12:33 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-17ubuntu1)
: No such file or directory
```

Here is a piece of my python script:

```
def download(self, a, donnees=None):                
      adresse = self.champ.get_text()
      self.v.fork_command('./pluzz.sh', '-u', adresse)  # calling the bash script
[...]
def __init__(self):       
      self.v = vte.Terminal()
      self.v.set_emulation('xterm')
      self.v.show()
      self.box1.add(self.v)
```

And a piece of the bash script:

```
echo -e "$VERT""DEBUT DU TRAITEMENT""$NORMAL"

#Recuperation de l' ID de l' emission
UserAgent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0'
ID=$(wget -q -U "${UserAgent}" "${URL}" -O - | grep -E "og:url.*content.*http://*" | sed 's+.*,\([0-9]*\).*+\1+g')

#wget du json conteant les infos
echo -e "$ROSE""-->RECUPERATION DU JSON""$NORMAL"
JSON="$(wget -q -U "${UserAgent}" "http://webservices.francetelevisions.fr/tools/getInfosOeuvre/v2/?idDiffusion=${ID}&catalogue=Pluzz&callback=webserviceCallback_${ID}" -O - | sed 's+\\/+/+g')"

#Recuperation des infos
echo -e "$ROSE""-->TRAITEMENT DU JSON""$NORMAL"
DATE="$(echo "${JSON}" | sed 's+.*date_debut..\"\([^\"]*\)\".*+\1+g')"
PROG="$(echo "${JSON}" | sed 's+.*code_programme..\"\([^\"]*\)\".*+\1+g')"
M3U="$(echo "${JSON}" | sed 's+.*url..\"\([^\"]*m3u8\)\".*+\1+g')"

#Recuperation du master M3U et traitement
echo -e "$BLEU""-->RECUPERATION DU FICHIER VIDEO""$NORMAL"
M3U2="$(wget -q -U "'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0'" "${M3U}" -O - | grep -E ".*index_2.*")"

avconv -i "${M3U2}" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "${PROG}_${ID}.mkv"
```

The bash script is running well in the console:

```
:~./pluzz.sh http://pluzz.francetv.fr/videos/coluche_un_clown_ennemi_d_etat.html
DEBUT DU TRAITEMENT
-->RECUPERATION DU JSON
-->TRAITEMENT DU JSON
-->RECUPERATION DU FICHIER VIDEO
avconv version 9.11-6:9.11-2ubuntu2, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 24 2014 06:12:33 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-17ubuntu1)
[hls,applehttp @ 0x1ebfe00] max_analyze_duration reached
Input #0, hls,applehttp, from 'http://ftvodhdsecz-f.akamaihd.net/i/streaming-adaptatif_france-dom-tom/2014/S18/J5/101152365-20140502-,398,632,934,k.mp4.csmil/index_2_av.m3u8?null=':
  Duration: 00:56:10.00, start: 0.100667, bitrate: 0 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 704x396 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0.2: Data: [21][0][0][0] / 0x0015
```

I hope my explaination is clear...
Thanks

**Edit:**
I've found a solution: Replace

```
self.v.fork_command('./pluzz.sh', '-u', adresse)
```

by

```
self.v.fork_command(None, ['/bin/bash', '-u', './pluzz.sh', adresse])
```

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that your problem is due to:

```
  self.v.fork_command('./pluzz.sh', '-u', adresse)  # calling the bash script
```

which assumes two things:

1. that the script is in the same directory as where the application has been launched from ;
2. that the script is executable and can be ran as standalone

but for 2., the script is missing the `#!/bin/bash` shebang header to tell the system that it is a shell script to be executed, and for 1. you should better use an absolute path, or a path relative to the current module's file.

You should instead use a path relative to the current script, or an absolute path:

```
import sys
import os
### if the pluzz script is in same directory as your python app
pluzz_script = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'pluzz.sh')
### explicitely run bash, to have it run your script
self.v.fork_command('/bin/bash', pluzz_script, '-u', address)
```

edit: rereading your post, it looks like it's not actually. Though you should take my previous advice to avoid any further problem with your script once you'll distribute it.

Your problem is that actually the file has not been downloaded, or couldn't be written and `avconv` can't access it. It's hard to tell what's wrong as the script does not let `wget`'s output through. Though you'd better convert that script to python and use a safe temporary directory to download the file in and work it out.

Here's a translation of your script in python:

```
# echo -e "$VERT""DEBUT DU TRAITEMENT""$NORMAL"
# retrieval of the show's id

from lxml import etree
import subprocess
import requests
import json
import os

### User defined values:
url='http://pluzz.francetv.fr/videos/doctor_who.html'
target_path=os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'Downloads')
###

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0'}

##### ID=$(wget -q -U "${UserAgent}" "${URL}" -O - | grep -E "og:url.*content.*http://*" | sed 's+.*,\([0-9]*\).*+\1+g')
p = etree.HTML(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text)
show_id = p.xpath('//meta[@property="og:url"]/@content')[0].split(',')[-1].split('.')[0]

##### get the JSON containing the show's data
##### JSON="$(wget -q -U "${UserAgent}" "http://webservices.francetelevisions.fr/tools/getInfosOeuvre/v2/?idDiffusion=${ID}&catalogue=Pluzz&callback=webserviceCallback_${ID}" -O - | sed 's+\\/+/+g')"
show_data_url = "http://webservices.francetelevisions.fr/tools/getInfosOeuvre/v2/?idDiffusion={show}&catalogue=Pluzz&callback=webserviceCallback_{show}"
show_data = json.loads("".join(requests.get(show_data_url.format(show=show_id), headers=headers).text.split('(')[1:])[:-1])

# retrieve data from the json
##### DATE="$(echo "${JSON}" | sed 's+.*date_debut..\"\([^\"]*\)\".*+\1+g')"
##### PROG="$(echo "${JSON}" | sed 's+.*code_programme..\"\([^\"]*\)\".*+\1+g')"
##### M3U="$(echo "${JSON}" | sed 's+.*url..\"\([^\"]*m3u8\)\".*+\1+g')"
# date = show_data['diffusion']['date_debut']
# prog = show_data['code_programme']
# m3u = list(filter(lambda x: x['format'] == 'm3u8-download', j['videos']))[0]['url']

p = requests.get(list(filter(lambda x: x['format'] == 'm3u8-download', show_data['videos']))[0]['url'], headers=headers).text

# M3U retrieval
##### M3U2="$(wget -q "${M3U}" -O - | grep -E ".*index_2.*")"
video_url = list(filter(lambda l: "index_2" in l, p.split()))[0]

##### avconv -i "${M3U2}" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "${PROG}_${ID}.mkv"

dest_file = "{}_{}.mkv".format(show_data['code_programme'], show_id)
subprocess.call(['avconv', '-i', video_url, '-vcodec', 'copy', '-acodec', 'copy', os.path.join(target_path, dest_file)])
```

or you can use to process `avconv`'s output:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['avconv', '-i', video_url, '-vcodec', 'copy', '-acodec', 'copy', os.path.join(target_path, dest_file)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()

for line in out:
    print(out)
```

so you can build a progress bar in your application's UI, instead of an ugly terminal output.

I have built another version of the code that has a better design, has a command line argument parser, and processes the line output to show a progressbar:

- https://gist.github.com/guyzmo/3b18193d6bea07bac37c

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your help, and yes the ID is not dwld by wget.

Comment: The result of your code is: [code]p: l: No such file or directory[/code]

Comment: If you want to see the total of both codes: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c9j0d21f4prhpaz/dPluzz_v2.1.py.tar.gz

Comment: ok, I've built an easy to use code/library that you can easily integrate to your existing code and leave the original bash script. It's in an open license, so please take it, use it and make something great out of it! I'm actually considering making it a lib and have it uploaded to pipy. Something like `pypluzz`.

Comment: basically, in my code, if you want to implement a graphical ui progress bar, just replace the `show_progress()` function in your code so you can reimplement a progress bar or some kind of ETA. Hope you'll like it ;-)